# Slide menu Swift

Tags: swift

Why the slide menu don't cover the current view?

Here is how is look:
[image: here is how is look]

it is anyone how knows what is going wrong and can help me

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

Add the menu layer as the last layer to the ViewController like this:

[image]

By doing this, it is always on the top layer and comes on top of the View